# Find users with a certain parameter, display the groups they belong to and count how many

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to get a number of how many people with specific titles are in specific groups.

What my approach is:

1. I am looking for users with specific titles.
2. I am looping over those users and looking for their groups they are in
3. Then I am looping over each group and trying to add .csv entry when there is a new one for that specific title, if group is listed, I am trying to just increment the counter.

I think that my approach is slow - every time I export and import .csv file, but I am sure there is a way to work on a imported file.

Also I have strange error: when importing test.csv I have like 10 entries instead of one. How to fix that?

My code:

```
clear
$Roles = Get-Content 'C:\Users\DWodzinski-admin\Documents\Titles.txt'
$Users = @()
Foreach ($Item in $Roles){
    $Users += Get-ADUser -Filter {title -like $Item} -properties title, SamAccountName | Select SamAccountName, title
    }
Foreach ($User in $Users){      
    $AdGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User.SamAccountName | Select Name
    foreach ($thing in $AdGroups) {            
            $name = $thing.name
            $csv = Import-Csv "C:\Users\DWodzinski-admin\Documents\test.csv"
            foreach($i in $csv){
                if($i.Group -eq $name -and $i.Title -eq $User.title) {             
                $i.Count += 1
                Export-CSV "C:\Users\DWodzinski-admin\Documents\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
                } else {
                $NewCsvEntry = @{
                 Title = $User.title
                 Group = $name
                 Count = 0
                 }
                [PSCustomObject]$NewCsvEntry | Export-CSV "C:\Users\DWodzinski-admin\Documents\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append                 
                }
                $i
            }
        }
    $csv | Export-CSV "C:\Users\DWodzinski-admin\Documents\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone want to know how I did it, I created ArrayList with CustomObjects:

```
clear
$Roles = Get-Content 'C:\Users\DWodzinski-admin\Documents\Titles.txt'
$Users = @()
$List = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
Name = 'Pierwszy';
Title = 'Czarny';
Count = 0;
}
$List.add($Object)
Foreach ($Item in $Roles){
    $Users += Get-ADUser -Filter {title -like $Item} -properties title, SamAccountName | Select SamAccountName, title
    }
Foreach ($User in $Users){      
    $AdGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User.SamAccountName | Select Name
    foreach($Group in $AdGroups){
        if($List | Where Name -eq $Group.name | Where Title -eq $User.title){
            $temp = $List | Where Name -eq $Group.name | Where Title -eq $User.title
            $temp.Count += 1
        } else {
        $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $Group.Name;
            Title = $User.title;
            Count = 1;
            }
        $List.add($Object)
        }
    }
}
$FilePathLocation = "C:\Users\DWodzinski-admin\Documents\test.csv"
$List | Export-Csv -Path $FilePathLocation -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed it so that it only imports your csv once, at the start, and exports (overwrites) it at the end. maybe it also fixes your issue with the 10 entries, try it out.

```
clear
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Users\DWodzinski-admin\Documents\test.csv"

$Roles = Get-Content 'C:\Users\DWodzinski-admin\Documents\Titles.txt'
$Users = @()
Foreach ($Item in $Roles) {
    $Users += Get-ADUser -Filter { title -like $Item } -properties title, SamAccountName | Select SamAccountName, title
}
Foreach ($User in $Users) {      
    $AdGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User.SamAccountName | Select Name
    foreach ($thing in $AdGroups) {            
        $name = $thing.name
        foreach ($i in $csv) {
            if ($i.Group -eq $name -and $i.Title -eq $User.title) {             
                $i.Count += 1
            }
            else {
                $newCsvEntry = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Title = $User.title
                    Group = $name
                    Count = 0
                }
                $csv += $newCsvEntry
            }
            $i
        }
    }
}

$csv | Export-CSV "C:\Users\DWodzinski-admin\Documents\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```